# Am getting "Illegal instruction" when running collect on iter::count

Tags: linux, rust

Running this:

```
fn main() {
    std::iter::count(1i16, 3).collect::<Vec<i16>>();
}
```

I get:

> thread '' panicked at 'capacity overflow', /home/tshepang/projects/rust/src/libcore/option.rs:329

That's what I'd expect when running this:

```
fn main() {
    std::iter::count(1i8, 3).collect::<Vec<i8>>();
}
```

But instead, I get this:

> Illegal instruction

In addition, syslog displays this line:

> Dec 27 08:31:08 thome kernel: [170925.955841] traps: main[30631] trap invalid opcode ip:7f60ab175470 sp:7fffbb116578 error:0 in main[7f60ab15c000+5b000]

Comment: `std::iter::count` generates an infinite set of items, and then you are putting that infinite list into a `Vector`. Is that your actual goal, or are you just exploring failure cases?

Comment: I was just curious what would happen, so yes, you could say I am just exploring failure cases.

Answer (score 6):

This was a fun adventure.

[`Iter::collect`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4a4c89c7a4a763c253a97ff04647f52aca6a5490/src/libcore/iter.rs#L470-L472) simply calls `FromIterator::from_iter`

[`Vec`'s implementation of `FromIterator`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4a4c89c7a4a763c253a97ff04647f52aca6a5490/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L562-L573) asks the iterator for its size and then allocates memory:

```
let (lower, _) = iterator.size_hint();
let mut vector = Vec::with_capacity(lower);
```

[`Vec::with_capacity`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4a4c89c7a4a763c253a97ff04647f52aca6a5490/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L210-L222) computes the total size of memory and attempts to allocate it:

```
let size = capacity.checked_mul(mem::size_of::<T>())
               .expect("capacity overflow");
let ptr = unsafe { allocate(size, mem::min_align_of::<T>()) };
if ptr.is_null() { ::alloc::oom() } // Important!
```

In this case, `i8` takes 1 byte, and the lower bound of an *infinite iterator* is `std::uint::MAX`. Multiplied together, that's still `std::uint::MAX`. When we allocate that, we get a null pointer back.

[`alloc::oom`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4a4c89c7a4a763c253a97ff04647f52aca6a5490/src/liballoc/lib.rs#L98-L103) is defined to simply abort, which is implemented by an **Illegal Instruction**!

The reason that an `i16` has different behavior is because it triggers the `checked_mul` expectation - you can't allocate `std::uint::MAX * 2` bytes!

---

In modern Rust, the examples would be written as:

```rust
(1i16..).step_by(3).collect::<Vec<_>>();
(1i8..).step_by(3).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Both now fail in the same manner:

```
memory allocation of 12297829382473034412 bytes failed
memory allocation of 6148914691236517206 bytes failed
```

Comment: Would this `Illegal instruction` also happen on Windows?

Comment: On Windows you'll get the "foo.exe has stopped working" pop-up dialog.